# Call HttpListener from external IP

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, httplistener, windows-server-2019

I have a very simple API in C# for test purposes. The API is created in a Windows Forms project

```
listener = new HttpListener();               
listener.Prefixes.Add(url);
listener.Start();
LogUtils.appendInfo("Listening for connections on: " + url);
//Handle requests
Task listenTask = HandleIncomingConnections();
listenTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

If I call http://localhost:8080/ I get response from API.

The problem is that if I call the API from another PC using the external IP address http://ExternalIp:8080/

I get this error:

> Bad Request - Invalid Hostname HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is
> invalid

What I have tried:

- I have put in the firewall a rule for port 8080 in incoming connections.
- I have tested with the ISS server that brings Windows Server 2019 off and on.
- I have created a 'applicationhost.config 'file in 'C:\Users\myUser\source\repos\myProyect.vs\proyectname\config' for <'binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8080:*" /> because my project not have applicationhost.config file.

Comment: An HttpListener [listens only for the URL prefixes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=net-5.0) passed in `listener.Prefixes.Add(url);`. That's what `Invalid Hostname` means. You can't use a single `url` for multiple IP and host names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @PanagiotisKanavos commented I can not use "localhost" in "listener.Prefixes.Add" for external request.

Solved by:

```
http://*:8080/
```

And run Visual Studio as administrator.

Comment: Hi, @user2983041. Does this solution solve your problem? If it is solved, you can click ‘✔’ to accept it as an answer. It is helpful for community members to solve the similar problems.